# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch on Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

I would like to make the **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** works on firefox for a smoothwheel script. It only works with Safari and Google Chrome. I don't know why, but it works on the "about" div. Why ?

HTML :

```
<button> CLICK </button>

<div id="home"> 
  Hello
</div>
<div id="about"> <span>This is about!</span></div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  margin:0;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   overflow:hidden;

}

#home {
  font-size:140px;
  height:1200px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}

button {
  position:fixed;
  z-index:3;
  font-size:30px;
  right:30px;
  top:30px;
}

#about {
  position:fixed;
  color:white;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  font-size:140px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);

}

#about span {
  position:relative;
  display:block;


}
```

Comment: `-webkit-` prefixes only work on WebKit browsers. Firefox is not a WebKit browser.

Comment: Are they a solution ?

Comment: You can check the [MDN page on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling). It states that Firefox is _not supported_, so I doubt you'll get that specific property working on Firefox.